# Cordova app does not scale on Windows retina device

Tags: html, css, windows, cordova, uwp

I'm developing a Cordova app and testing it on a Windows 10 machine with a high-DPI screen. `window.devicePixelRatio` returns `1.5`.

I have defined a `viewport` like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

However, when the app runs it does not properly scale like the rest of Windows. Everything is tiny and if I check the document width from the console, it's now 1.5 times the actual screen width.

Setting `initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=2` does not change anything.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a bug with the MSAppHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this has something to with MSAppHost. The app was targeting Windows 8.1 and running in `MSAppHost/2.0`. Targeting Windows 10 makes it run in `MSAppHost/3.0` which does properly scale.